# Angular server side login error handling in component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have code to login at a server. Therefore I use the angular HTTP client and an authorization service. If I post incorrect data to the server, I get the expected response from the server, but execution must stop somewhere due to angular internals.

The following console output is logged:

```
post data=login (in auth.service.ts)

ERROR 
Object { headers: {…}, status: 401, statusText: "Unauthorized", url: "http://localhost/login", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/login: 401 Unauthorized", error: {…} }
(in core.js:4002)

​
```

Can anyone explain why?

Thanks.

### in service

```
login(loginUrl: any, body: { pass: string }) {
  console.log('post data=login');
  return this.http.post(loginUrl, body, httpOptions);
}
```

### in component

```
login(): void {
    this.authService.login(loginUrl, data).subscribe((serverLoginResponse: any) => {

       // successful log in, continue to do stuff.

      }, (serverLoginError: any) => {
        console.log('error in subscribe err');
        console.log(serverLoginError.statusText, serverLoginError.status);
        if (serverLoginError.status === 401) {
          this.loginForm.controls['password'].setErrors({invalid: true});
        }
      });
     });
  }
```

### in template

```
<input #passwordField id="password" class="form-control" type="password" formControlName="password" required>
<div [hidden]="!loginForm.controls['password'].hasError('invalid')" class="alert alert-danger">
   There is no user account matching the entered data! Try again.
</div>
```

Comment: Can you confirm in the developer tools "Network" tab that the request is sent with the proper data and the expected message is returned? This line -> `headers: {…}, status: 401, statusText: "Unauthorized"` makes me suspicious.

Comment: I would also recommend encapsulation of the angular HttpClient module. From my experience, it is less convenient than a regular Promise-like object. Try to edit `authService.login` function to completely parse the request and return a Promise for the component to handle. This is a rather cleaner approach.

Comment: @fingeron The line is correct, I expect a 401 response.All I want to achieve is to visualize the error to the user in the view.

Comment: @fingeron Can you provide an example of how you would implement your second comment (promise based approach)? All I found out in regard to Http requests is to use observables, which I have never used before and therefore still seem a bit strange to me..... promisses would be much better.

Comment: Sure thing, I'll try to sum everything up in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, following Angular's guide [Making a POST request](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request) using their built-in HttpClient module, it is instructed to pipe to `catchError` with an Error handler. Try to see if that works.

Also, from my personal experience, I would recommend encapsulation of HttpClient module under a Promise-like object. For example:

```
login(url: string, data: { pass: string }) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.post(url, data, options || {})
            .subscribe(
                response => resolve(response),
                err => reject(err)
            );
    });
}
```

Then, your component function would look like:

```
login() {
    this.authService.login(loginUrl, data)
        .then((serverLoginResponse: any) => {
            console.log('Request successful, check login results.');
        })
        .catch((serverLoginError: any) => {
            console.error('error in subscribe err');
            // I would first examine the error response
            console.log(serverLoginError);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's awesome and conceptually much better to understand and handle (if you know promisses). Just for comparison could you also show me how I could relay the error response using the observable like in the Angular link you provided. I assume there would be a new Observable thrown/returned somehow in the `handleError()`.
In the end now this also raises the question: "What is the benefit of `observables`?"

Comment: Honestly, as much as I appreciate Angular's work, I think the decision to use an observable for the HttpClient is a little off. Requests are one time events with a trigger and an async response. It's the literal purpose of a Promise. Observables have a bunch of extra features that are thoroughly explained as a part of the RxJS library. Very useful indeed, but again, in my opinion, not for HTTP requests.

Comment: If you really wanted to use the instructed way and catch the error within the component, then maybe returning the `HttpClient.post` observable to the component, and piping it to `catchError` there could work.